# In python, why does math.floor(4.9999999999999999) == 5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, precision, floating-accuracy

I know this is some floating point error, but I had read that python has infinite precision, so this kind of thing shouldn't happen.

Self contained runnable code:

```
import math
math.floor(4.9999999999999999)
```

Comment: Python's `float` certainly does not have infinite precision.

Comment: ... and what you read was about `int`.

Comment: Similarly, don't use `math.sqrt` to check if a large integer is a perfect square: the float roundings will give you false positives: `b = 36028797018963970 ** 2; math.floor(math.sqrt(b - 1)) == math.sqrt(b - 1)` is true.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's rounded up to `5.0` before `math.floor` is called.

```
>>> 4.9999999999999999 == 5.0
True
>>> import math
>>> math.floor(5.0)
5.0
```

One way to get correct behavior is using `Decimal` (and not using `float` or `math` at all):

```
>>> import decimal
>>> int(decimal.Decimal('4.99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999'
).to_integral(rounding=decimal.ROUND_DOWN))
4
```

FYI The Python `float` type is an [IEEE 754 64-bit float](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), thus it can have (at most) 2**64 different values. The decimal constant 4.9999999999999999 cannot be represented exactly, so it's rounded to some other value (which happens to be the exact representation of 5.0) when Python parses the source code. Without the quotes, the float is rounded before it gets converted to Decimal:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal(4.9999999999999999)
Decimal('5')
>>> decimal.Decimal('4.9999999999999999')
Decimal('4.9999999999999999')
```

Comment: Is there a way for me to make this work like expected? Using Decimal or some other library perhaps?

Comment: @EkanshdeepGupta: Yes, `Decimal` works, see my updated answer.